# How to derive the relationship between log yield and log price?

Tags: fixed-income, continuous-time

Usually, people write $y_t^{(n)}=-\frac{p_t^{(n)}}{n}$ where $y, p$ and log yield and log price respectively. My question is how do one derive this expression?

Note that $e^{-Y_t^{(n)}\cdot n}=P_t^{(n)}$ if $Y,P$ are the continuous yield and price of the one dollar $n$ period bond respectively at time $t$. Now, if we take logs, we get
$$-Y_t^{(n)}\cdot n=p_t^{(n)}.$$
Therefore, we have $Y_t^{(n)}=-\frac{p_t^{(n)}}{n}$ which differs from the equation from the first paragraph. What went wrong?

Comment: I believe Cochrane and Piazzesi *define* the "log yield" using the first expression. However it is not the same as the log of the yield, which is what you are assuming in your second derivation.

Comment: IMHO "continuous time yield" would be a better name for this than "log yield".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misnomer by Cochrane and Piazzesi. It should simply be called the continuously compounded yield.